# Arrow function return parameter as property of object

Tags: javascript, typescript, arrow-functions

I would like to return the parameter `word` of my arrow function as the property of the object key. But the object returned contains the property `"word"` instead.

```js
lines = ["first row","second row","third row"]
let newLines = lines.map((item, index)=> {
                    let wordsPerLines = item.split("\s");
                    return wordsPerLines.map(word => ({ word : index}))
            }
            );
            console.log(newLines);
```

This is the output:

```js
[
  [
    {
      "word": 0
    },
    {
      "word": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "word": 1
    },
    {
      "word": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "word": 2
    }
  ]
]
```

I would like to have instead this output :

```js
[
  [
    {
      "first": 0
    },
    {
      "row": 0
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "second": 1
    },
    {
      "row": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "third": 2
    },
    {
      "row": 2
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Though your question was closed, you have an issue with splitting strings. You are putting a regular expression in as a string. Either use `.split(' ')` or `.split(/\s/)`

Comment: @chazsolo, you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the property name in square brackets:

```
word => ({ [word] : index})
```

So:

```
return wordsPerLines.map(word => ({ [word] : index}));
```

The `[ ]` can contain any expression. That's evaluated, and the string value of the result will be the property name.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript takes the keys in objects literally. To use a variable, change your return code to the following:

```
return wordsPerLines.map(word => ({ [word] : index}))
```

The brackets let js know it's a variable, not literally `'word'`.